# How to change rendering of dropdown in jquery ui autocomplete attached to a class?

Tags: jquery-ui

I copied some code from the jQuery UI site and appended it to my own:

```
$('.field_values') // class that all input fields are a member of in my html
// here I am skipping .autocomplete, which works
// next comes the copied code
.data( 'ui-autocomplete' )._renderItem = function( ul, item ) {
return $( '<li>' )
.append( '<a>' + item.label + '<br>' + item.value + '</a>' )
.appendTo( ul );
 }
;
```

I cannot find any documentation on this _renderItem function. Another stackoverflow question/answer suggested that the problem might be having a class instead of an id. But I must have a class, because there are many fields.

How can I get this to work with my class?

Comment: Did my answer help you in any way?

Comment: It sure did, but I just got around to testing it a few minutes ago. I voted you up and gave you the coveted green checkmark.

Comment: Perfect! Just was curious if it worked and it seems so ;)

Comment: Yes, it's great. Now I am working on figuring out how to get my css to affect the styling. But that is less critical than the functionality itself. Thanks again.

Answer (score 32, accepted):

Look what I tried. It seems to work for me. I hope I understood your question right.

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    //...here is the projects source

    $(".field_values").autocomplete({
        source: projects,
        create: function () {
            $(this).data('ui-autocomplete')._renderItem = function (ul, item) {
                return $('<li>')
                    .append('<a>' + item.label + '<br>' + item.value + '</a>')
                    .appendTo(ul);
            };
        }
    });
});
```

Here is a [**working example**](http://jsfiddle.net/SirDerpington/bx8Ye/143/).

With your method it seems like the custom rendering only gets applied to the first autocomplete input you click but with the [create](http://api.jqueryui.com/autocomplete/#event-create) event it gets applied to each autocomplete with the class `.field_values` when it's created.

Created this fiddle with jQuery v 1.9.3 and jQuery UI 1.10.3 (works fine too with UI 1.9.1)

Here's the source code of the `_renderitem` function on [github](https://github.com/jquery/jquery-ui/blob/master/ui/autocomplete.js#L537).

Comment: Would the one who down voted my answer explain why? I'm curious

Comment: @SirDerpington, I am stuck in a similar situation, pretty much tried everything but can't get it to work, the ajax is calling the controller and its returning records as well, but when I want to change the stylying with renderItem it just doesnt show the list... Please help.

Comment: It worked with`jquery-3.4.1` and `jquery-ui-1.12.1`

Answer (score 0):

```
.autocomplete( "instance" )._renderItem = function( ul, item ) {
      return $( "<li>" )
        .append( "<a>" + item.label + "<br>" + item.desc + "</a>" )
        .appendTo( ul );
    };
```

This is how it works for me.

Comment: The working language of SO is English; please translate the comment.