# jQueryUI version 1.10 autocomplete - how to set _renderItem?

Tags: jquery-ui, jquery-ui-autocomplete

Since I switched from jqueryui 1.8.1 to 1.10.x I realised that my custom item renderer doesn't work anymore:

```
Uncaught TypeError: Cannot set property '_renderItem' of undefined
```

What is different in new jqueryui versions?

Here my code:

```
$("#lexicon-search-input")
        .autocomplete({
        ...
        }).data("autocomplete")._renderItem = customItemRenderer;
```

This was working on jqueryui 1.8.1 but doesn't on 1.10.3.

One more thing: I use multiple autocomplete fields. Therefore, I can not set it globally. For instance, $.ui.autocomplete.prototype._renderItem = customRenderItem would work, but will affect all of my autocompletes.

Answer (score 71, accepted):

Using `ui-autocomplete` instead should solve your issue.

```
$("#lexicon-search-input")
    .autocomplete({
    ...
    }).data("ui-autocomplete")._renderItem = customItemRenderer;
```

See the [documentation](http://jqueryui.com/autocomplete/#custom-data) for a tutorial on how to use `_renderItem` (especially the source code)

If you want to create the `_renderItem` function for multiple autocompletes with class `yourClass` just use it in the [`create`event](http://api.jqueryui.com/autocomplete/#event-create)

```
$('.yourClass').autocomplete({
    create: function() {
        $(this).data('ui-autocomplete')._renderItem ....
    }
});
```

See another [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/16372823/2240272) of me on that topic.

Comment: Thank you so much. I didn't realised that naming has been changed from  "autocomplete" to "ui-autocomplete".