# What is the autocomplete instance option and what is it used for?

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-ui, autocomplete, jquery-ui-autocomplete

Taken from the jQuery autocomplete documentation found here [jQuery autocomplete](http://api.jqueryui.com/autocomplete/#method-instance):

```
instance()

Retrieves the autocomplete's instance object. If the element does not have an associated instance, undefined is returned.

Unlike other widget methods, instance() is safe to call on any element after the autocomplete plugin has loaded.

This method does not accept any arguments.
Code examples:
Invoke the instance method:


$( ".selector" ).autocomplete( "instance" );
```

Ok so what does that mean? What would I use this for? I am refactoring someone else's javascript code and here is an example of it in use:

```
ProjectForm = {

  init: function() {
    // This code removes a selected license
    $(document).delegate( 'a.remove_license', 'click', function() {
      $(this).closest('.license').remove();
      if( $('.chosen_licenses').html() === '' ) {
        $('.chosen_licenses').html('<div class="license inset">[None]</div>');
      }
      return false;
    });
    this.license_autocomplete();
  },

  license_autocomplete: function() {
    // This code performs the autocomplete and adds html element
    $('#add_license').autocomplete({
      source: '/autocompletes/licenses',
      select: function(event, ui) {

        if( $.trim($('.chosen_licenses div:first').html()) === '[None]' ) {
          $('.chosen_licenses').html('');
        }

        var html = (''+
        '<div class="license col-md-5 no_margin_left">'+
        '  <div class="col-md-6">#{name}</div>'+
        '  <div class="col-md-5 pull-right" style="margin: 0 20px 20px 0">'+
        '     <a href="#" class="btn btn-danger btn-mini remove_license col" data_id="#{id}">'+
        '        <i class="icon-trash"></i> Remove</a>'+
        '  </div>'+
        '</div>')._f(ui.item);
        $('.chosen_licenses').append(html);
      }
    })
    .autocomplete( "instance" )
    ._renderItem = function(ul, item) {
      return $( "<li></li>" )
        .data( "item.autocomplete", item )
        .append( "<p>" + item.name + "</p>" )
        .appendTo( ul );
    };
  }
}
```

If I remove that line the results from `source` do not display. Can someone tell me what it does?

Comment: `_renderItem` is attached to an instance; e.g., http://stackoverflow.com/q/17568630/438992.

Comment: Thanks for the reply Dave. The attached answer has no mention of .autocomplete( "instance" ) though and doesn't answer what it does.

Comment: the documentation also implies that the .autocomplete("instance") isn't necessary either for _renderItem to work too.

Comment: It isn't; you can attach it in multiple ways.